# how to use Telegram official api inside telegraf library

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf, telegraf.js

I'm trying to create a telegram bot using [telegraf library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegraf) and npm

and the problem is I can't find a way to use all telegram methods like `channels.getFullChannel` or `channels.getMessages` inside telegraf api...

there are methods in telegram official docs that I want to use them, like [this one](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.getMessages), but I don know how to access it with telegraf instance.

i use this for my code:

```js
const Telegraf = require('Telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.TOKEN);

bot.command('logmessages', async (ctx) => {
  const res = ctx.telegram.channels.getMessages('@username')

  console.log(res)

  ctx.reply('check out console')
})
```

but what is get in the console is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMessages' of undefined

at /app/node_modules/telegraf/composer.js:143:56
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

***I should mention*** that in the official docs is pointed that these methods are accessible by Bots.

I also tested

```
ctx.channels.getMessages('@username')
```

didn't work either

Comment: Do you have any code or any errors you can add?

Comment: i edited the question!

Answer (score 0):

hello u should modify Your Class Constructor and set channelMode True

```
const bot =  new Telegraf(Token, {

channelMode: true
```

})

then u should use event for geting channel message something like that

```
bot.on('channel_post', (ctx) => {
 

console.log(ctx.channelPost);
```

})

**it will log every channel post in all channel. You can use Simple if condition for log this channel u want**

Comment: this returns the new messages when they are sent... what I need is to access all messages in the history of a channel